# How do I call a value from a list inside of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a some data that I put into a pandas dataframe. Inside of cell [0,5] I have a list of times that I want to call and be printed out.

Dataframe:

```
GAME_A                                                  PROCESSING_SPEED
yellow_selected                                                       19
red_selected                                                           0
yellow_total                                                          19
red_total                                                             60
counters                [0.849998, 1.066601, 0.883263, 0.91658, 0.96668]
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = '>')
print(df.iloc[0])
proc_speed = df.iat[0,5]
print(proc_speed[2])
```

When I try to print the 3rd time in the dictionary I get `.`. I tried to use a for loop to print the times but instead I get this. How can I call the specific values from the list. How would I print out the 3rd time `0.883263`?

```
[
0
.
8
4
9
9
9
8
,

1
.
0
6
6
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because with the way you are loading the data, the column 'PROCESSING_SPEED' is read as an object type, therefore, all elements of that series are considered strings (i.e., in this case `proc_speed = "[0.849998, 1.066601, 0.883263, 0.91658, 0.96668]"`, which is exactly the string the loop is printing character by character).

Before printing the values you desire to display (from that cell), one should convert the string to a list of numbers, for example:

```
proc_speed = df.iat[4,1]
proc_speed = [float(s) for s in proc_speed[1:-1].split(',')]
for num in proc_speed:
    print( num)
```

Where `proc_speed[1:-1].split(',')` takes the string containing the list, except for the brackets at the beginning and end, and splits it according to the commas separating values.

In general, we have to be careful when loading columns with varying or ambiguous data types, as Pandas could have trouble parsing them correctly or in the way we want/expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `proc_speed[index]` as you have set this variable as a list. Here is a working example, note my call to `df.iat` has different indexes;

```
d = {'GAME_A':['yellow_selected', 'red_selected', 'yellow_total', 'red_total', 'counters'],'PROCESSING_SPEED':[19,0,19,60,[0.849998, 1.066601, 0.883263, 0.91658, 0.96668]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

proc_speed = df.iat[4, 1]

for i in proc_speed: 
    print(i)

0.849998
1.066601
0.883263
0.91658
0.96668

proc_speed[1]

1.066601

proc_speed[3]

0.91658
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert with apply, it's easier than splitting, and converts your ints to ints:

```
pd.read_clipboard(sep="(?!\s+(?<=,\s))\s+")['PROCESSING_SPEED'].apply(eval)[4][2]

#  0.883263
```